# Low Pass Filter For Square Wave Through An Optoisolator

Tags: filter, opto-isolator, low-pass

I've got a higher voltage square wave input that I'm feeding through FOD817B Optoisolator. The square wave frequency is in the range of 30 to 300 Hz.

The Circuit is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc24no.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've tried to filter the Circuit as shown above, it works ok, but it's still quite noisy.

(Scroll Down To Bolded Area)
Here are some screenshots from the scope:

No Filter Higher Freq
[[image: No Filter Higher Freq]]Higher Frequency

No Filter Low Freq(noisier)
[[image: No Filter Lower Freq]]

With Filter(low freq.)
[[image: With Filter Circuit]]

Here is the 12v input Signal with no filtering
[image: Input Signal No Filter]

**After realizing my scope was not properly grounded to the circuit**
Here are the correct signals
[image]
On Occasion I would see the Optoisolated Signal create the similar/same sharp downward spike in the middle of the positive cycle of the square wave. Like the 12 Unfilitered Signal, but sharper.

Comment: First, reverse your diode. Second, what is the amplitude of your square wave?

Comment: oops. The real circuit has the diode correctly oriented. Amplitute is 12V on input.

Comment: I see no decoupling capacitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I suspect you have drive problems. I'd suggest monitoring the voltage across R2 as a measure of the current through the LED. If it's not perfectly clean (and I suspect it's not) that's your problem. I'd guess that your low phase has a major spike about a millisecond before nominal transition to low, and the high phase of the drive signal shows a major drop about 5 msec in, down to about a volt or less with a rather low rate of recovery.

If the drive signal is clean, try a new optocoupler. Every once in a while devices do very strange things.

Comment: Thanks, I will try another optocoupler. I also found some Optocouplers with built-in Schottkey Diodes. This might be what I need..There seem to be so many different types but all seemingly have the same specs... Here's one: [FODM611](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FO/FODM611.pdf)

Comment: @GisMofx - Frankly, given the regularity in timing, I'd really focus on the drive.

Comment: I tried a new Optocoupler and same result. I scoped the input signal and added the screenshot to my question. It's pretty square  but the falling edge has some rippling.

Comment: "It's pretty square" - not!

Comment: @GisMofx - Aaannd we have a winner. The falling edge does not have ringing, it has the same sort or exponential-decay spikes you see on the first trace. It also has just the right sort of spike just before the trailing edge. Get a new driver.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I can't get a new driver..It's actually an output tachometer pulse from an ignition unit.

Comment: @GisMofx - Then you're going to have to clean up the signal.

Comment: @GisMofx - Also, try taking a picture of your tach output at low frequency. Wanna bet what it will look like?

Comment: So what's the best way to clean the signal in this case? It's much noisier at "idle", and a little bit of throttle it cleans up a little bit and looks like the last photo I posted. Think the FODM611 or similar is enough to resolve the issue?

Comment: @GisMofx - The optocoupler is fine. Your problem is not that the optocoupler is corrupting your signal - it's the fact that the signal is crappy. The first thing you can try is simply making a different low-pass filter. Try a 10 uF cap. Play around. If all you're trying to is measure frequency, some combination of low-pass filter and a comparator may be enough. Oh, and by the way, you do not have your filter connected the way you think you do. Recheck it. You should not be getting those spikes to ground if it is connected properly, so your original cap may be OK. Just fix the connections.

Comment: @GisMofx - Come to think of it, with your low-pass filter, I'm virtually certain that you are still looking at the optocoupler output. This is wrong. You must look across the capacitor, instead. If you do this, you may even find that reducing the capacitor will work.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm slightly confused, What's the correct setup for a low pass filter in this circuit? It's resistor and then a cap to ground, right?[Low Pass Schematic](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/images/CRLowPass.png)

Comment: @GisMofx - Yes, but the low-pass function only applies at the capacitor. So that's where you need to monitor it. Anyways, you don't much care about what's happening at the optocoupler output - the MCU is not connected there. Connect your scope across the capacitor.

Comment: I'm scoping it now

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I updated my post and added new scope images. Turns out I didn't have my scope grounded to the circuit(total amateur  move), so I was getting some bad readings..I still occasionally see a downward spike in the middle of the positive cycle of the square wave output.

Comment: This as far as I can take it on this question. If the spike is big enough to cause problems, get a picture of it and start a new question about it. Good luck. (Shameless plug: don't forget to select my answer if it helped enough.)